# Refactoring with OR operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, refactoring

This currently doesn't work. However, I believe the solution would be along these lines? I just need an error to be thrown if a coordinate is over 7.

```
class Game
  def initialize(args={})
    @dragon = args[:dragon] || [0,5]
    @knight = args[:knight] || [1,3]
    valid?
  end

  def valid?
    raise ArgumentError, 'Please enter values between 0 and 7' unless ( ( (@dragon[0]) && (@dragon[1]) && (@knight[0]) && (@knight[1]) ) > 7 )
  end
end
```

Thus, something like:

```
new_game = Game.new({dragon: [2,10], knight: [1,5]})
```

would throw an error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is this code working properly?

Comment: Bustkiller - it does not. Edited my question. Thanks for the calling out.

Comment: Although I think Keith Bennett's answer is correct, I would like to point out that your code was not working because instead of comparing each of the values to 7 separately you were "adding" them as if they were boolean, and then making a single comparison with 7

Comment: `( (@dragon[0]) && (@dragon[1]) && (@knight[0]) && (@knight[1]) ) > 7` does not seem right.   Above expression will return value of `@knight[1]` always and compare it with 7

Comment: Thanks guys. You're correct. I originally had '||' instead of '&&'. That solution was failing, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
valid = @dragon.concat(@knight).all? { |n| (0..7).include?(n) }
```

This irb session shows a case of success and failure for that test:

```
2.3.0 :009 > [2,10].concat([1,5]).all? { |n| (0..7).include?(n) }
 => false
2.3.0 :010 > [2,7].concat([1,5]).all? { |n| (0..7).include?(n) }
 => true
```

Comment: Thanks Keith. Works perfect! Will accept in 4 minutes.

Comment: Alternatively, `valid = ((@dragon | @knight)-(0..7).to_a).empty?`.

Comment: OP, why the rush to accept? A quick acceptance may discourage other, possibly better, answers and short-circuit those still working on answers. Many here wait at least a couple of hours, some much longer. (These comments have nothing to do with Keith's answer, which I upvoted.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Your expression works, and is a little more concise, but I feel that it is a bit further from the high level validation logic. I think using `(0..7).include?` communicates more clearly to the reader the nature of the validation.  Also, in this case the range is a manageable size so calling `to_a` is not a problem, but in other cases it could result in a large array. BTW, I upvoted your comment. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
raise ArgumentError, 'Please enter ...' if (@dragon | @knight).any? {|i| i > 7}
```